# Regex to find URLs not in tags

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am breaking my head on this:

I am trying to find URLs in Javascript with regex.

Update: I use Javascript on serverside, so I can not walk through the DOM

```
(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|)(www\.)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.[a-zA-Z\.]{2,6}(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\?=\/#%&\+-]+|\/|)/gi
```

The above sample is working great. 
But I need to change the regex that Urls won't be found in: `href="url"` and not in `<a ....>url</a>` but in anything else like `<p ...>url</p>` or `<div ....>text text text url, url, url text text</div>`

Can anybody help?

Thank you and cheers
Michael

Comment: Use the HTML DOM for that. Walk through the tree and put each qualified tag's `innerHTML` to the regex test. Trying to regex HTML tags will only result in poverty and sorrow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Include the a-tag with the not/exclude operator.

Comment: @Three previous comments. You've interpreted the question wrongly.

Comment: Don't downvote him just 'cause he didn't know you're not supposed to regex html. Someone's gotta tell him, and he didn't even know to ask the question. :)

Comment: @RobW, Maybe. Shed some light.

Comment: I didn't know underscores are forbidden in URLs...

Comment: @JonathanM Look below. Judging from the question, the OP wants to only match URLs which are textnodes, and ignore `<a>` elements.

Comment: @RobW, Yep. That's what my comment was based on: use the DOM to go through all elements, and, for the qualified ones (non-anchors), use the regex on the `innerHTML` (or `value`).

Comment: @JonathanM `.innerHTML` converts HTML tags to strings. If you walk through the DOM, and check the `innerHTML` property, it's possible that an anchor child is also selected. You really have to recursively walk through the DOM, and only parse text nodes (Node type 3).

Comment: I can't use the DOM, because I use Javascript on serverside.

Comment: @MichaelM. - 0_0 JavaScript is used on the client side.  Did you mean PHP?

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler if you allowed a non-href url to be the text of an a element.
As you require, you need to avoid any child nodes of the a elements, in case you have an url like text in a span or strong or whatever child of an a.

```
   function someurls(node){
        var A= [], tem, rx=/^https?\:\/\/[^\s]+/g;
        if(node){
            node= node.firstChild;
            while(node && node.tagName== 'A') node= node.nextSibling;
            while(node!= null){
                if(node.nodeType== 3){
                    if((tem= node.data.match(rx))!= null) A[A.length]= tem;
                }
                else A= A.concat(someurls(node));
                node= node.nextSibling;
                while(node && node.tagName== 'A') node= node.nextSibling;
            }
        }
        return A;
    }
```

//
alert(someurls(document.body).join('\n')